# Merging consecutive dates for a group together

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table with employees that looks like this:

| Name | Department | Manager | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202101 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202102 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 2 | Manager X | 202103 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 2 | Manager X | 202104 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202105 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202106 |
| Employee 2 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202101 |
| Employee 2 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202102 |

I need to build a view that shows the data in the following format:

| Name | Department | Manager | Valid_From | Valid_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202101 | 202102 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 2 | Manager X | 202103 | 202104 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202105 | 999912 |
| Employee 2 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202101 | 999912 |

So far, this is what why code looks like:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT [Name], Department, Manager, Valid_From = min([Date]), Valid_To = max([Date]),
      RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], ORDER BY max([Date]) DESC)
   FROM TestingTable
   WHERE ([Date] IS NOT NULL)
   GROUP BY [Name], Department, Manager
)
SELECT [Name], Department, Manager, Valid_From,
    CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN 999912 ELSE Valid_To END AS Valid_To, CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Is_Latest
FROM cte
```

The output is this - it groups the intervals that employee 1 has worked in department 1, while I need it in 2 different chronological intervals.

| Name | Department | Manager | Valid_From | Valid_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202101 | 999912 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 2 | Manager X | 202103 | 202104 |
| Employee 2 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 202101 | 999912 |

I experimented a bit with the lag and lead functions to compare the dates, but I'm lost.

Comment: What does `999912` mean?

Comment: Your cte is fine, as far as i can't understand the row rownumber that seems complete wrong, but why do you make a CASE WHEN and the same goes for the rownumber , remove the cte and keep the select without the row number

Comment: Do you have "gaps" between work dates?

Comment: Your column, `date` isn't actually a *date* though; dates have a year, month *and* day portion to it. It also looks like you're storing the value as an `int`, which also isn't a `date`.

Comment: Yes, the Date column has the year and month in an int format, the day is not relevant because all changes are done at the beginning of the month. @Larnu

Comment: The current status (combination of Employee, Department, Manager) needs to have an end date of dec 9999, that's why I have added the last part, with CASE WHEN @nbk

Comment: It's December 9999, to show that it's an ongoing contract, with no end date.  There are no gaps between work dates, it's just the year and month in an int format @SalmanA

Comment: What happen to the row `Employee 1 - Dept 1 - 202106` ? why it is not in your expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to group consecutive year-months per employee-department-manager together. It could be done like so:

```
with cte1 as (
    select name
         , department
         , manager
         , datefromparts(date / 100, date % 100, 1) as yymm
    from t
), cte2 as (
    select *
         , case when lag(yymm) over (partition by name, department, manager order by yymm) = dateadd(month, -1, yymm) then 0 else 1 end as new_grp
    from cte1
), cte3 as (
    select *
         , sum(new_grp) over (partition by name, department, manager order by yymm) as grp_num
    from cte2
)
select name
     , department
     , manager
     , min(yymm) as valid_from
     , max(yymm) as valid_to
from cte3
group by name, department, manager, grp_num
order by name, valid_from, department, manager
```

Note that I had to convert the year-months to dates for easier comparison. Result:

| name | department | manager | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 2 | Manager X | 2021-03-01 | 2021-04-01 |
| Employee 1 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-01 |
| Employee 2 | Dept 1 | Manager X | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 |

Replacing the last `valid_to` for each employee with `9999-12-01` is trivial e.g. you can check if `lead(valid_from) over (partition by name order by valid_from)`  is null.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a kind of gaps and islands problem with a twist regarding the open intervals detection

```
select distinct Name, Department, Manager, 
      min([date]) over(partition by Name, g) fromd,
      max([date]) over(partition by Name, g) tod
from (
  select *, sum(flag) over(partition by Name order by [date]) g
  from (
    select Name, Department, Manager,
      case when lead(name) over(partition by Name order by [date]) is null then 999912 else [date] end [date],
      case when department != lag(Department, 1, '') over(partition by Name order by [date]) 
            or  Manager != lag(Manager, 1, '') over(partition by Name order by [date])
           then 1 else 0 end flag
    from tbl
  ) t
) t
order by fromd
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0192513803eba6a0fc65fe513600aa4a)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with tbl1 as (select 
    [name]
    ,[department]
    ,[manager]
    ,[date]
    ,ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by name, department, manager order by name, department) as rownum 
from employees)
select  [name]
    ,[department]
    ,[manager]
    ,[date] as [valid_from]
    ,(select [date] from tbl1 t2 
    where t2.[rownum]  = t1.[rownum] + 1
    and t1.name = t2.name
    and t1.department = t2.department
    and t1.manager = t2.manager
    ) as [valid_to]
from tbl1 t1
where rownum % 2 = 1
order by name, valid_from
```

its missing the 999912 as I dont understand the logic for replacement in the bottom two rows.